# Booting Ubuntu from 1 GB usb drive

Tags: system-installation

In the tutorial it says I need at least a 2 GB usb drive to boot ubuntu from a thumb drive. I only have a 1 GB usb drive right now. The ISO file is ~ 904,000 KB, which can be stored on the usb drive. I have tried putting it on the usb drive with the Universal USB installer to no avail. It seems that this does not matter.

I just received a new Samsung Windows 8 laptop, and it is not giving me the option of booting from the USB stick. I have turned off the 'fast-startup' and from what I've read this should have given me the option to boot from the usb stick.

My end goal is to be able to dual boot both Windows 8 and Ubuntu on this laptop. I guess I am just looking for some advice from here.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

What tutorial are you using? There are some applications for making Linux live USB drives, like UNetbootin from the Ubuntu Software Center, that can be used to make an Ubuntu live USB for installing Ubuntu using a 1GB USB flash drive. However starting from Ubuntu 14.04 and onward, the Ubuntu iso is too large to put on a 1GB flash drive using UNetbootin.

In fact, it is possible to make an Ubuntu live USB flash drive for installing Ubuntu that is only 36MB in size by using the Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit Mini CD iso. There is more information about how to make an Ubuntu live USB flash drive using the Ubuntu Mini CD in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd/689263#689263).

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the created ubuntu live-usb by changing the boot-order in bios(usb as the first option).

or

Selecting USB option from the boot menu in bios.

Comment: Where is this option in the BIOS? I've looked around and it seems that there is no option for it?

Comment: is there any boot tab in bios?