# Installation problem - can not boot from USB drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I have major problems trying to install Ubuntu on a friends computer. She is having her exams and is in real need of that computer, so we're both stressed at this point. I would be very happy and relieved to get some help :-)

I have wiped the hard drive, and created several bootable USB drives. None of the latter are functioning - getting me here (picture below) and no further:

[image: Screen. Freezes here, does not enter splash screen]

I have tried several installations on several USB drives. Using RUFUS, Win32DiskImager with official Ubuntu images, following the tutorial [here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0).

Also tried installing Chromium from bootable USB. Same result.

I hope these four images of my BIOS are of some use:

[image: BIOS 1]

[image: BIOS 2]

[image: BIOS3]

[image: BIOS 4]

**Here are the computer specifications:**
13.3" Full-HD LED 1920x1080 16:9 Matt IPS-screen
6. gen Intel Celeron N3450-processor 1.1GHz ~ 2.2GHz, 4 cores
4GB DDR3L SO-DIMM RAM
32GB eMMC SSD
Intel HD Graphics 500, DirectX 12 compatible
No dvd/cd
Bluetooth 4.0
802.11 b/g/n wireless networks card
1 x mini HDMI
1 x USB 3.0
1 x USB 2.0
Polymerbatter, 7.4V 5400mAh
Full Range AC adapter 36W 100-240V 50-60Hz 12V 3A
Size 315.7 x 208.7 x 13,5 mm (BxDxH)
Weight: 1.3 kg

Comment: 1. Does some other computer boot from the USB pendrive? 2. Please turn off secure boot in a UEFI/BIOS menu, and Fast Startup in Windows, and try to boot from USB again.

Comment: Also, try booting from the USB drive in legacy mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the First Boot Option in the BIOS still links to the Windows Boot Manager, which can not find a Windows-Installation anymore. Set the USB-Stick to position #1.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already changed that and tried. Still no success. The computer finds the usb and tries to boot from it, but it can't.

Comment: Change the BIOS boot order 1 to a UFD that has Live Ubuntu written to it. Was the UFD  formatted to FAT32? Has Secure Boot (shown customised) been disabled?