# How to install ubuntu 18.04 server minimal?

Tags: system-installation

When I install Ubuntu server the footprint is 3.5GB no matter what I do. If I install debian it is about 700MB. Is there no way to install Ubuntu without installing all of those packages? Just a bare bone install.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. How do you install the server? For me, choosing only OpenSSH Server and Basic Ubuntu Server gives about 1.5 GB. You can see what large packages got installed by running `dpkg-query --showformat='${Installed-Size;8}, ${Package}\n' --show '*' | grep -v '^,' | sort -nr | head -20`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd) The minimal server option of the Ubuntu Minimal CD is the [Basic Ubuntu server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDcz0.png) option.