# Blank screen after bootloader either live or install

Tags: system-installation

I want to install the latest lts ubuntu on my desktop but keep getting a black screen after bootloader login . It works on dvi but not VGA 
.  My main VGA monitor is Samsung s22c150 21.5inch HD and the dvi is only a 19inch LCD. Don't know the make as its over 6 years old.

My PC specs 
Ryan 5 1600x 
Drevo ssd 120gb
R9 380x nitro 4gb
Gigabyte ab350 
Max bran 1000w psu 
Corsair h60
2tb segate 
I have tried using yumi to install ubuntu on a USB and the same with rufus
I downloaded it twice from ubuntu main site 
I have also tried f6 and tried all options and luck. I do remember it working on previous version but then I upgraded and black screen. I tried ubuntu 12.04 and the screen is being detected as a laptop screen in settings with no option to change the size and also the wifi wont connect really want to switch to ubuntu instead of windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)

Comment: Black screen after boot screen on VGA adapter on a r9 380x

Answer (score 0):

Try Alternate CD. It usually works. Installer uses better hardware detection than LiveCD, so after the textmode (Alt. CD) installation, the system usually works well.

If it does not, you can boot in safe mode and edit the configuration files manually (it'll be another question). Or there can be a workaround (for example, GPD Win + Lubuntu 18.04 requires a single closing/opening the lid after each reboot; the screen is black before you do it).

There are also some parameters you can tweak on the first LiveCD screen (sorry, I don't remember how to access them on UEFI boot). Maybe some of them can help with initial display mode.

Comment: I have tried ubuntu 12.04 and now its showing main screen as laptop and cannot change size and also wifi will not connect. I also tried linux mint and same black screen after the boot loader

Comment: 12.04 have some problems with wifi. On GPD Win, neither 12.04 nor 16.04 works without tweaks. Only 18.04 does. If you can use cable connection and one display, can you upgrade to 18.04 now?

Comment: Cant use the lan as my PC to far away from the router. Only wifi. I'm going to try another type of linux

Comment: I have ordered a display port to VGA adapter. I'll report back if it works or not.

Comment: I also tried opensuse and the same thing happened  black screen after boot loader. The VGA port is fine in windows but not linux

Comment: I have now tired ubuntu 14.04 and its working but cannot change the screen size as its showing as unknown