# Ubuntu Wont boot for some reason

Tags: boot, fsck, nomodeset

I have ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and after power black out, the system hangs at ubuntu logo. Infact bootable pendrive wont boot(same pendrive boots on a same system of my friend). I tried to boot using 'nomodeset' removing 'quiet splash', it hangs at the

it stops at the log

> Start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes
>
> .
>
> .
>
> Started D-Bus System Message Bus

But, for some reason Tails OS would boot normally, I did run fsck on the file system(from tails OS), it is clean, yet no luck

What and why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)

Comment: @Prakhar I really don't think your partitions or hard drives are at fault here. the power black out could have damaged any of the more important components of your system. your CPU, your ram, your GPU. and Tails OS boots because none of the more complex operations of any of these components are required durring it's boot process. try running prime95 (https://www.mersenne.org/download/) on a cpu+RAM test and see if any of the threads have crashed after 3 hours. if they have you may have a damaged component. you can test your gpu with this : https://benchmark.unigine.com/heaven?lang=en

Comment: @tatsu Thanks for the links, will test and update the results, I suspect same what you said, but was not aware of any utility that can help me diagnose the problem !

Comment: @karel I doubt my query is what link you provided. I am not having problem with bootable pendrive, the same pendrive works on a separate but exactly same machine.

Comment: @tatsu I agreed and share same suspicion of  what you said and thankful for the links you provided. What is that I implied was opposite to your comment?

Comment: my bad I got the notification, followed the link and assumed it was the last comment (for karel) and read that as if it was for me.

Comment: Tail OS boots but not Ubuntu because Tail OS is far more lightweight than Ubuntu. By the same token replacing the 1.5GB Ubuntu .iso with the 65MB Ubuntu Minimal CD will provide an elegant solution to your problem which is rooted in your computer's hardware, not in the Ubuntu live USB.