# Trying to install ubuntu. But my pc wont boot up. Whats wrong?

Tags: system-installation, rufus

I downloaded ubuntu from its website, copied it to a usb using rufus.

But my pc doesn’t boot up windows 10 or anything when the usb is plugged in. It just runs and the screen acts like the pc is shutdown.

I have waited about 30 minutes before unplugging the usb and then i had to shutdown my pc using the power button.

I tried the same usb to another pc (laptop this time) and it worked. What could be wrong with my pc?

Comment: Probably not an issue, but did you verify the integrity of the download/write-to-thumb-drive using check-disc-for-defects option. You've not told anything about the machine, but it sounds like a hardware issue to me.  Is the pc the correct architecture for your downloaded image?  Have you validated it's memory (memtest), checked it's hdd/sdd (ie. SMART to ensure in good state) etc.

Comment: have you tried the usb on another pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into this problem before. I think you need to modify your BIOS.

1. Have a working live USB. If you don't know how to do this, check out the [website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd) Karel referred you to, it has links.
2. Once you have done that, restart the computer with to USB inside. As soon as you restart the computer, start clicking escape.
3. A menu will pop up- select BIOS.
4. Go to System Configurations.
5. Go to Boot Options
6. Put Internal USB CD/DVD on top.
7. Put USB CD/DVD from the second to the top.

Note: to change the positioning of your menus, highlight your target; then press f5 to go down, and f6 to make it go up.

8. When your done making changes, press f10. Save your changes. Your computer will reboot, and start booting the live USB.