# UNetBootin can't boot Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, unetbootin

I'm a beginner in Linux. I've had my usb prepared with UNetBootin with Ubuntu 18.04 Live x64 LTS.

The problem is, my PC won't boot to usb drive. Even though I've change the boot sequence and try many option, UEFI, legacy, etc.

I've even tried different method of usb installers, Etcher, Rufus and they just stuck in blank screen after ubuntu logo displayed.

Please help this beginner so I can start experiencing this new world of open source.

My PC spec is ECS H61 mainboard.
Intel core i5
Ddr3 4gb
Seagate 500gb HDD.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Ubuntu logo displayed" means that you DID boot from the USB. Step 1: [Verify that you downloaded the .iso without corruption](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu).

Comment: 1. Please tell us about your graphics chip/card: Brand name and model; 2. Have you checked with `md5sum ` that your iso file was downloaded correctly? 3. Maybe the following links can help you: [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) and [Why Doesn't my Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186435/why-doesnt-my-bootable-usb-boot).

Comment: According to the manufactures (ECS) the graphic card is Intel® HD Graphics 2500/4000(Intel 3rd gen CPU)

Comment: I'm sure the iso is not corrupted. Stil I repeat the process and now it says the graphic card is not supported. Will try the above solutions for now and come back with the results. Thanks

Comment: Most Intel graphics chips work with Ubuntu, so this might be an unusual case. Maybe it helps to use the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`.

Comment: Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download or  https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 . Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.

Comment: There are quuite a few H61 type motherboards at the ECS support site. https://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/ECSSearch/EN/H61  Which do you have?

Comment: My ECS board is H61H2-MV.

Comment: Tried different Version of Ubuntu Desktop. 18.04.4LTS (bionic beaver) ubuntu stuck in login loop. Tried the Ctrl Alt F1 terminal solution i find in this forum n still cant login. Tried 16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus) same thing happened, login loop. 14.04.6 LTS and even the 12.04.5 LTS version still stuck in login loop. However today my friend tried to instal an old vga card to the board and it worked! An ATI Radeon vga card. Succesfully login to desktop ubuntu. Any info on this?

Comment: Thanks a lot. nomodeset seems to solve my problem. I was able to choose recovery mode n successfully login to desktop. Meanwhile now we're trying to upgrade the ubuntu version. Will post updates here. Many thanks for everyone's help here.