# 16.04 32-bit LiveUSB made with Rufus fails to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, live-usb

I'm trying to create a bootable USB with Rufus for my 32-bit laptop, but everytime I try and boot from USB it just boots back to Windows 10. It's been doing this everytime and I don't know how to fix it...

Can anyone help? I've been following Rufus tutorials and such, but it never seems to work.

Comment: In Rufus, please make sure PARTITION SCHEME is set to MBR and FILE SYSTEM is set to FAT32

Comment: It's set to FAT32 and MBR. I can't boot it still.

Comment: 1. Please tell us about your computer and your graphics chip/card: Brand name and model (for both of them) - It can help us help you; 2. Have you checked with md5sum that your iso file was downloaded correctly? 3. Maybe the following links can help you: [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) and [Why Doesn't my Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186435/why-doesnt-my-bootable-usb-boot).

Comment: I'll try that. It's just I can't access the internet on the laptop I'm trying to boot Ubuntu on, when I did a clean install of Windows 10, my computer lost its network drivers.

Comment: Is it possible for you to borrow a computer in order to access the internet? Or maybe use a smart-phone?

Comment: I have a desktop, and checked the md5sum. It's a good iso file according to the program I used.

Comment: Good :-) Maybe you can try if you can boot the other computer from your USB drive. If that is the case, you can focus on the boot process in your laptop computer.

Comment: Do you have an older laptop with Windows (or Mac) on it, in order to use Rufus to re-create installation medium?