# Boot ubuntu from external hdd

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation, external-hdd, boot-repair

I have installed Ubuntu on my external HDD. but my HDD not appear in menu boot. Please help me fix this problem. Tks

Comment: 12.04 or 18.04?

Comment: When you reboot your system, did you go to the boot device menu (requires a keystroke which varies depending on your PC BIOS, so I can't tell you what to press because I don't know which PC you have)? If so, what options do you see there?

Comment: yes. I have gone to the boot device menu. and just see internal hdd and usb boot

Comment: The following links may help you find the problem: [Why Doesn't my Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186435/why-doesnt-my-bootable-usb-boot/) and  [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) and  [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)

Comment: Your USB boot option might be your external hard drive, unless you have a usb stick also connected.

Comment: IF UEFI, any default install does not create and ESP - efi system partition on any drive other than first drive seen (If none exists) and your should have gpt partitioning. And then Ubiquity installer only uses first drive's ESP. You need to manually create ESP on external drive and reinstall grub or use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
&  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I fixed the problem with Boot-Repair. and external HDD has appeared in boot menu. thanks a lot