# Boot from usb issue

Tags: boot, 20.04, lts, usb-installation

Whenever I try to boot from the usb the screen blacks out. I need to switch to windows ASAP for some work. Any help will be much appreciated.

The screen looks like the image below.

[image: screen blacks out]

Comment: Which is this os? Whenever you post, you should mention which os with which version you need to resolve the issue?

Comment: You need to refer boot-repair

Comment: If UEFI install, you should always be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu (same key you used for installer, often f12). Do you have nVidia? If so you need driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: It's 20.04 LTS version. @Akshat Zala

Comment: No I don't have Nvidia. It's just intel HD. I already tried using 'nomodeset' which is the open source driver. But it's the same. I mean I can use Ubuntu. The operating system is loading. But it need to install windows. So when I select the UEFI or boot from USB the screen goes black. I haven't got any solution yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't my Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186435/why-doesnt-my-bootable-usb-boot) and [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/q/689258/)