# USB iso burnt using Rufus boots into a message "Unable to find a medium container a live file system"

Tags: live-usb

I followed [the tutorial on how to burn an Ubuntu iso to USB on Windows 10](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to the letter, except I was burning Ubuntu v20 and not v18.

When I boot from this USB on a laptop, I receive a full screen of repeated errors:

```
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sr0: No Medium Found
```

Followed by a single:

```
Unable to find a medium container a live file system
Attempt interactive netboot from a URL?
yes no (default yes):
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: That tutorial is written for Ubuntu *yy.mm* systems, eg. 20.04 LTS and not Ubuntu Core 20 or *yy* based products.  Ubuntu has had *yy.mm* (*deb* based) and *yy* (*snap* only) products since 2016, they differ.

Comment: @guiverc, I was burning `ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64`

Comment: Writes to thumb-drive (*flash*) media can fail on occasion (in my experience 5-8% fail) so assuming you validated your ISO, I'd just re-write it again as the error message (assuming a *yy.mm* release and not a *yy* product) reads like a corrupted ISO.  I often verify a failed write by booting on a second box (of the same type; bios/uefi/secure-uefi & another type - to prove it's a bad write.. but that's optional)

Comment: Did you verify the ISO?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0   (Please be precise with details as they matter, [Ubuntu Core] 20 is a different Ubuntu product to [Ubuntu] 20.04...)

Comment: There are quite a few reasons a bootable USB is not booting, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186435/why-doesnt-my-bootable-usb-boot The first thing I would do is check the ISO's MD5SUM to make sure ir is not corrupt and the second is try the USB in another computer, the third is try a different USB tool such as Etcher or Universal.

Comment: Same iso, different USB worked. Thanks folks.

Comment: Yes it does @karel, thank you.

Comment: @Steve If the duplicate link answered your question please confirm it by clicking "Yes" next to where it says "Does this answer your question?" in the light blue banner above your question.