# Dell Latitude 3199 No OS, No Bootable Device, No Primarily Hard Drive, No SATA options or Boot Sequence options

Tags: boot, dell, sata

How can I install Ubuntu from USB if there are no boot sequence options, the primary hard drive is set to None. The SATA is set to none. There’s no OS installed currently.

Comment: Put your usb in, restart and enter bios boot menu - can you then find your usb to select? Are you sure your usb media works?

Comment: [This link to a question at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186435/why-doesnt-my-bootable-usb-boot) contains answers with a lot of tips what to check and/or modify to make your computer boot from your USB boot drive. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186435/why-doesnt-my-bootable-usb-boot/1186484#1186484) points to the answer that focuses on the early stages of boot, how to check and/or modify the UEFI/BIOS system.

Comment: I have two Dell Latitude computers, and have no problem booting from USB. Maybe check if you can upgrade the UEFI/BIOS system.