# Ubuntu Server starts only from BIOS

Tags: boot, server

I did a clean installation. The [boot priority](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7wIN.jpg) is also fine. But the system [won't boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJZcQ.jpg) until I [manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao1Pk.jpg) go to the bios and boot from my HDD. How can I fix it?

Laptop model is: NP305V5A-A05DX

Comment: When you go into BIOS, do you have to reset it every time? Or does it remember the boot priority? If you need to reset it, then your CMOS battery is probably dead.

Comment: @mpboden No, the settings and boot priority are saved after rebooting

Comment: Is this an UEFI system, but you installed in BIOS mode? It then defaults to UEFI boot, but you have to manually override that to boot in BIOS mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally (with most installers that I know) the installed system will boot only in the mode that was running during installation.

- So if you install in BIOS mode alias CSM alias legacy mode, the installed system will boot in that mode
- and if you install in UEFI mode, the installed system will boot in UEFI mode.

You must tweak the system in order to make it boot both in BIOS mode and UEFI mode. It is possible according to the following links,

- [Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS). The shortcut to extract from a compressed image file can be a good alternative, but will not create an encrypted file system.
- [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step).

This is what to do if you want a portable system, bootable in most PC computers with 64-bit architecture.

---

If you intend to use the server in one particular computer, it is easier. **When installing Ubuntu Server, be sure to boot in the mode that you intend to run it after installation**, UEFI mode or BIOS mode alias CSM alias legacy mode.

It is probably easier and faster to make a fresh installation than to tweak the existing system to make it boot also in the other boot mode.

---

If still problems, you can refer to the following link and links from it to look for possible things to tweak,

- [Why Doesn't my Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186435/why-doesnt-my-bootable-usb-boot/)