# Cannot boot up to any flavor of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I have an HP Pavilion laptop. The model number is 15-cx0056wm. I can not get the live USB version of Ubuntu, or Kubuntu, or Lubuntu or Xubuntu to boot up. It boots on the other computers I own. I don't believe it to be a UEFI problem, because I get to the GRUB screen where it says "Start Ubuntu". But I disabled safe boot and enabled legacy mode just in case, and it still did not boot. It begins to boot, but then it hangs after a few seconds. The dots on the screen stop moving, and the hard drive indicator light stops blinking. I waited 20 minutes on one boot, just to make sure I was waiting long enough, and nothing changed. With Lubuntu, there is an option for "Safe Graphics Mode". Choosing this option does not make a difference - it still hangs. Does anyone have any ideas? Are any boot log files saved to the USB drive that I could look at?

Comment: The usb-thumb drive is a RO device (as written) so no data/logs can be stored to it. The data (*cow* or copy on write) is copied to RAM & operates from there; so logs exist in RAM until you shutdown or reboot. The obvious is did you verify the ISO post-download (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and write to media (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck) (CD refers to whatever media is used; be it thumb-drive)?   You didn't provide any release details (ie. what age of software stack are you trying to boot?)

Comment: Chances are with many ISOs tried (you mention four) it's not *squashfs* errors (bad ISO or write to media), but without specifics as to age of software stacks (ie. releases of Kubuntu, Lubuntu,Xubuntu or Ubuntu used) little else comes to mind other than that question (which releases?  what age?  if 18.04 (2018-April reelase) which; 18.04, 18.04.1, 18.04.2, etc)   For best help please be specific.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)

Comment: All of the versions were 18.04. The USB stick is 2 years old, but I doubt that is a factor because it boots up fine on my other computers.

Comment: Boots up fine on other computers - so the other computers have identical hardware thus read the same areas of media (kernel modules/drivers)? and not using other kernel/modules stored elsewhere on media; otherwise your logic is flawed (the test reads ALL of the *squashfs* & other files).  Ubuntu 18.04?  not 18.04.1? or 18.04.2? or 18.04.3? etc  2 years old I don't know what to do with as two years ago was before 2018-April when 18.04 was released.

Comment: Apparently I was not specific enough. I tried several different versions of Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu and Xubuntu. None of them will boot on my HP Pavilion laptop. As of right now, I have the live version of Lubuntu 18.03.3 LTS on a USB drive that boots fine on my Toshiba Satellite laptop, on my wife's Dell laptop, and on a generic desktop that I built myself. It will not boot on my HP Pavilion laptop. It loads GRUB, and begins to boot, but hangs a few seconds into the process.