# ASUS ROG STRIX B550-F motherboard - Ubuntu USB won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I just built a new system with a Ryzen 7 3700X on a ASUS ROG STRIX B550-F motherboard. Running Windows 10 Pro.

I want a Ubuntu dual boot so I have a new 2 TB hard drive to install it on.

When I try to boot my USB appears to initially start (I get the menu for run or installation). Whether I choose install or run the light on my USB stick then goes out like it's not being accessed and all I get are a lot of Wait Loop Timed Outs, Then a lot of Hexadecimal with a final message of

```
Kernel Panic- Not Syncing Fatal exception in interrupt.
```

I have also seen a message that it seems to be unable to access the USB port.

I have made a bootable iso USB with Ubuntu using Rufus and I've tried using balenaEtcher for the creation. I've used every format (Fat32, NTFS, even GPT).

I've tried it with 20.04 and 18.04.5 versions of Ubuntu. I have tried disabling CSM. I even unplugged the SSD with my Windows installation.

I'm at a loss!! Any Help would be vastly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you verify the ISO after download and before writing to your boot media? (thumb-drive etc) ie. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and then validate the write to your install media? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck for 18.04 where CD is whatever media you use to boot, it's automatic on 20.04). If you can't verify on that box, I'd do the verify on another box, however if it fails to verify successfully on second box I'd assume write to media failed or is faulty & return to ISO validation).

Comment: Have you tried booting your USB on a different computer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)

Comment: Yeah I did verify it Thank you Guiverc.  CS Cameron... tried it on a older laptop fired right up, loaded and installed.  karel... Ty  So whatever is going on it has to be on my new build and it's something with the USB ports or the Kernel.

Comment: Can you disable fast boot? When you get the menu to run installation, is it black or purple? What is the name of the bios you are using?

Comment: Yes I tried it with the fast boot disabled as well. Bios is AMI 0243 x64 and the screen is black

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help... it's a setting in the BIOS with the IOMMU. It has to be disabled or CHAOS lol.

Comment: it's ok to post your answer here to your own question

Answer (score 1):

Go into BIOS search for the IOMMU setting and disable it.