# Ubuntu installation from USB freezes after "Checking disk" is done

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded the ubuntu 20.04.1 ISO & used rufus (3.12) to burn it to a usb drive. Everything was going great, until I finally booted from the drive, but then, it froze right after the "checking disk" was done. It didn't even get to it's install gui. It just froze until I shut my pc off. I didn't tweak the bios at all before attempting to install. Any way I can fix this? I don't want to be stuck with Windows!

My machine is the Acer Aspire 3 (I haven't heard great things about linux compatibility with this laptop).
CPU: AMD ryzen 5 35000U,
GPU: Radeon Vega mobile

Comment: Two possible workarounds are to skip the optional disk checking or to use the text only Ubuntu 20.04 installer: [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/q/689258/)

Comment: How do I disable disk checking?

Comment: When you see a [message in white text on a black screen](https://www.ricmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/how-to-install-ubuntu-20.04-01.jpg) that the Ubuntu installer has started disk checking there is a `Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress` message at the bottom of the screen that tells you how to stop the disk checking and continue on to the next step of the installation process.

Comment: Are there any potential side-effects with that approach?

Comment: There are no potential side effects with that approach. Please consider the case of a user who made a partitioning error in the Ubuntu installation and had to immediately reinstall. Clearly in such a case the user wouldn't need to repeat the same disk check  that was done only 30 minutes before, so the user would press Ctrl+C to quit it.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I don't see an option for Install Ubuntu, instead there is just two options Ubuntu and Ubuntu safe mode. Both the optiona goes to a checkdisk screen and stalls after checkdisk status reach 100%. I also tried skipping the checkdisk. But then it freezes again. Please help.