# Is Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 15ARH05 supported by Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, lenovo, ideapad

I bought a Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 15ARH05 laptop and tried to install Ubuntu on it, but it seems that this laptop is not supported by Ubuntu, so I wasn't able to install it.

After that I went to a professional technician, but they also were not able to install Ubuntu or any other version on my laptop.

Can anyone tell me that if this laptop is supported by Ubuntu and how can I install it?

Comment: I suggest that is a question for the computer maker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)

Answer (score 2):

After I ran over some issues in Fedora 34, Solus os 4.2 and Arch, my way of using my laptop was to install Ubuntu 20.04.2 and install the 5.11.10 kernel from: [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11.10/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11.10/)

All you need is the `*generic*` and the `*all.deb` files, just 4 files. So run these commands:

```
cd /tmp
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11.10/amd64/linux-headers-5.11.10-****-generic_5.11.10-****_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11.10/amd64/linux-headers-5.11.10-****_5.11.10-****_all.deb 
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11.10/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.11.10-***-generic_5.11.10-****_amd64.deb 
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11.10/amd64/linux-modules-5.11.10-****-generic_5.11.10-****_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./*.deb
```

Hope I have helped.

Comment: I should note that, in general, it is not a good idea to save the `.deb` files in the `/tmp` directory and then run `sudo apt install ./*.deb` from there. The reason is that `/tmp` is a temporary storage directory and could contain more `.deb` files, which would get executed too. Obviously, this is not something you'd want. If you would save the `.deb` files in a new directory, either inside or outside `/tmp`, or if you first make sure that `/tmp` does not contain other `.deb` files, then running `sudo apt install ./*.deb` should not be an issue.