# Black screen while installing ubuntu server 20.04.3

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, uefi, dell, grub-legacy

I have been attempting to install Ubuntu server 20.04.3 onto a Dell Precision 5810 using both legacy and UEFI. After I press enter to install the OS, the screen goes black and I am not able to see if the install, or if anything is happening. I have tried both a flashed USB by Etcher and a DVD to install. Both have the same outcome. Are there any other options for installation?

The video card is a Nvidia NVS 310. The monitor is a Dell SE2216H. Using a display to HDMI cable between the two. The OEM motherboard does not have a VGA connection.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you tried to press "STRG + ALT + F1" ? Any messages? The Xeon CPU does not have an integrated graphic-card. Possibly you can try it with an old card or a card from a friend for the test.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)

Comment: I was able to obtain an AMD GPU temporarily. I was wasting too much time trying to make it work. 

Thank you for your help.