# Ubuntu freezes after booting from USB drive on 2020 Macbook Air

Tags: system-installation, macbook, macbook-air

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my MacBook Air and I get stuck on the screen that gets displayed immediately after you boot off the USB drive where you are prompted to either try out or install ubuntu (e.g. [step 4 in the installation instructions](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#4-boot-from-usb-flash-drive)).

It is either frozen, or my mouse and keyboard are for whatever reason not active. I noticed my keyboard doesn't light up on this screen.

**System specs**

- MacBook Air 13-inch, 2020
- macOS Catalina version 10.15.7
- Memory: 8 GB 3733 MHz LPDDR4X
- Processor: 1.1 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5
- Graphics: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 1536 MB

Comment: You may want to run Ubuntu in a VM on that machine rather than try to install it on bare metal. There is no way to get the internal WiFi to work and some of the necessary drivers will require hand-crafted kernel modifications. The keyboard and trackpad will not work during installation, so you’ll need an external. If you *really* want to continue, [here’s the keyboard and trackpad driver](https://github.com/roadrunner2/macbook12-spi-driver/tree/mbp15), the [T2 driver](https://github.com/MCMrARM/mbp2018-bridge-drv/), and [a kernel patch](https://github.com/aunali1/linux-mbp-arch) 

Comment: @matigo that seems like a really good answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)