# Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS Failing to install

Tags: boot, 20.04, usb, acer

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on my Acer Aspire V5-132. It came with Windows 8, and I dual-booted it with Linux Mint 20.3 MATE Edition. Somehow, it erased both Operating Systems, leaving my hard drive with nothing to boot off of. Before this happened, the night before, I had flashed a USB Drive with Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS using Etcher https://etcher.io/. So this morning when I saw this happen, I turned on my Acer laptop, booted off the USB Drive, and it was booted off of it. Now I had to install Ubuntu... FAIL. I can only use the Try Ubuntu feature, not the Install Ubuntu button. Please help! (I can put pictures if needed)

Edit: Screenshot of Disks app on Try Ubuntu: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DG1a9cxsq3NzGkWOy9aNUeF_EJQCIDTf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It sounds like your hard drive has died of old age. Using the **Try Ubuntu** option open the **Disks** app and see if the internal drive is recognized in the left panel. If so, select the that drive in the left panel and see its partitions in the main (right) panel. Take a screenshot and upload the picture in imagur.com. Finally [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1402728/edit) and add a link of the uploaded screenshot in your question. If you don't see the internal drive recognized by the **Disks** utility, then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: This is the screenshot of the Disks App, does the hard drive look okay..? (i see the hard drive, its a 500gb one.) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DG1a9cxsq3NzGkWOy9aNUeF_EJQCIDTf/view?usp=sharing (yes this is run with the Try Ubuntu feature, its running off of a usb)

Comment: "Now I had to install Ubuntu... FAIL. ": describe in detail how you attempted the installation, and at what point it failed. Provide the exact error message if any.

Comment: dont worry this exact usb is being erased and replaced with windows 8.1 64-bit

Comment: should i stop it before its too late or no

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)

Comment: The "Disks" seems to show your main disk with a large ext4 partition on it already.  can you get further by clicking on the "Install Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS" on the desktop?