# I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.2 on a windows 10 desktop - will not install

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.2 on a windows 10 desktop. There are 3 drives on the computer.
M.2 SSD 1 TB with windows 10
NVMe 1 TB data drive
NVMe 1 TB blank drive - to have Ubuntu installed on it.
USB stick 64 GB with Ubuntu 22.04.2 installer on it.
The BIOS has the USB drive as a boot option.  When I try to install the BusyBox comes up with error - /dev/st0 not found invalid media.
I have spent an enormous amount of time on it, tried everything I have seen on the net and still no go.
This is my last effort to get it installing.
I have successfully installed Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi and HP laptop with no problems and have been working with windows hardware and software for a long time.  This is really annoying.
Can anyone help please ?

Have fixed the problem.  Just installed 22.04.1 with no problems at all.
It seems the 22.04.2 setup / install is the problem.

Happy days.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)