# 23.10 Live USB Installer freezes at "Copying files..."

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

Nothing else outputs beyond this line in the terminal view:

`Oct 13 16:38:40 ubuntu subiquity_event.2438[2438]: subiquity/Ad/has_support_GET`

It's been like that for more than an hour.

Comment: Did  you hashcheck the downloaded ISO?  What flavor/release Ubuntu are you installing (23.04 I guess with subiquity).

Comment: @ubfan1 Yes, I did hashcheck it. I'm trying to install 23.10.

Comment: hi @hicham-labidi what utility did you use to prepare live usb for Ubuntu 23.10? Thanks.

Comment: @Jags balenaEtcher

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)