# Can not install Ubuntu via bootable USB

Tags: usb-installation, 23.10

I have downloaded Rufus and Universal USB Installer. I have tried to install Ubuntu several times with each of those but all give me the same results at the end. I get stuck at this step [image]

I clicked the use a device and it give me 3 options. Some of you may says that I choose the wrong one, but I have try 3 of them for several time and still can not install ubuntu. The 3 options show me the window starting screen as usual. Please help me.

I use Windows 10. I want to install [ubuntu-23.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso](https://releases.ubuntu.com/mantic/ubuntu-23.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso).

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details; so we're somewhat limited in what help we can provide. Your issue appears to be related with booting external media, and how you do this is device (ie. machine make/model/firmware) specific, and you provided no details of your hardware either.  If you don't write a Ubuntu ISO correctly, or use your machine external-media-methods correctly - you'll boot your installed OS (ie. windows if you have windows installed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: You're ending up in the Windows bootloader, you shouldn't get this close to Windows!! Installation of Ubuntu should start before this.

You need to go into your BIOS and select boot from USB. If you update your question with your precise hardware details, we may be able to provide more specific instructions.

Comment: I have edited my post, sorry this is my first post actually. Is it enought ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/q/689258/) and [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)