# Unable to install Ubuntu multiple relasease and even Linux mint

Tags: boot, acpi

[[0.534654] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCSATA.P

RTO._PSC.GP27], AE_NOT FOUND (20230331/psargs-330) [ 0.534743] ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.PCIO.SATA.PRTO. PSC due to previ ous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529)

0.537167] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCIO._OSC.L 1C3], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330)

[ 0.537321] ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.PCIO._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhL6P.jpg)

Comment: You've provided no specifics; as Ubuntu offers various releases & various ISOs for each release using different installers (eg. Ubuntu 23.10 offered two installers for 23.10 Desktop, another for Server, two options for *flavors*) plus there are kernel stack choices for LTS release (*default set by ISO you opt to download/install with*). You do mention a non-Ubuntu system that is off-topic here (Ubuntu based isn't Ubuntu). Your details are without any context as you provided no specifics.

Comment: I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 all LTS desktop versions and as a trial Linux mint, sorry this is like just my second time trying out ubuntu or linux the last time was like 3 years back when I had dual booted along side my windows 10, this time around I tried installing Ubuntu on the SAME DEVICE BUT NEW SSD as I wanted to learn Linux seriously but this time it's giving me the above errors regardless of which release I try and the error occurs when I am trying to boot into the installer itself from the usb media and also post install and then never boots

Comment: It's helpful if you're specific; Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is EOL or EOSS (*depending on architecture*) and off-topic here, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ISOs exist that use the 5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13 & 5.15 kernels but you gave no specifics except for 20.04; likewise 22.04 is available with many ISOs (and kernels 5.15, 5.19, 6.2, 6.5..) ; and that's just kernel details directly; installers also can vary by ISO downloaded.  For us to provide specific advice, we need to know what exactly you're asking about.

Comment: 3 years back when I dual booted on this device I had no issue but it was on the OEM hardrive, I was able to run Ubuntu 18.04 LTS if my memory serves me right had it for a few weeks then had to reflash my harddrive with fresh windows 10 as I was facing problems on the windows end. The device is quite old a Sony VGN CR34GN running on a Intel cemtrino, I had no issues installing windows 10 on the new SSD which I tried post several failed Ubuntu installation attempts.

Comment: @guiverc if you have any suggestions on trying to install a specific kernel or release I don't mind giving it a try and will post my results I am very new to Ubuntu and I am not sure how to determine the specific kernel and usually just download image from the downloads page of the Ubuntu website

Comment: FYI:  If the machine is old; I'd suggest using the older GA kernel stack when you try... Just as I mentioned the various kernels available for 20.04 & 22.04... your 18.04 may have provided the key as it likewise as kernels from 4.15 thru 5.4 available... I do have hardware that would only boot 18.04 when GA or 4.15, also HWE 4.18, 5.0 kernels were used but not later 5.3, 5.4... Another machine that would only use 18.04 with 4.15 & 4.18, 5.0 & 5.3  but not the 5.4. What exactly worked with your 18.04; what kernel stack actually worked for example is a huge clue.

Comment: Ok thank you so much I will try an older kernel and see if it works and post my results 

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS tells us only the software stack age (ie. 2018-April which is what 18.04 is)... unless we know the product (eg. Server, Desktop, *flavor*) we know little more.  LTS releases are available via re-spins of media (*to reduce upgrades post-install if installed*) and with some products this impacts the kernel stack, ie. 18.04.2 Server uses the same kernel as 18.04.1 or 18.04 media; however 18.04.2 Desktop uses a newer kernel... thus the full ISO detail (18.04, 18.04.1... 18.04.6) matters as well as product detail (eg. Desktop, Server, Lubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE, Xubuntu etc)

Comment: I tried to install and run Ubuntu 16.04.7 desktop amd64 iso image and running into the same problem, tried it on all 2 of my ssd and my old harddrive all show the same problem I am thinking of it could be a bios ?since it's on legacy not uefi as far as I know

Comment: Update I was somehow able to get debain to boot on the device and gave me some confidence, I tried again to boot with 22.04.4 LTS desktop USB media  and chose minimal install during installation and wiped the whole disk with the debian clean and for some reason it worked without any problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)

Comment: Not exactly but it helped thankyou @karel

Comment: For some unknown reason Canonical stop offering ISOs of bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CDs for about three years despite it being the only possible way of installing Ubuntu on some models of computers, usually legacy computers.

Comment: Ooh that's interesting,I will explore more about minimal CD ISO, I do have a legacy bios system , can't update if to uefi, for now ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS desktop is working, but will explore the minimal CD ISO @karel